# toggleClass on Click jQuery Issue

Tags: jquery

I am having the super standard 'View more' button and then on click it becomes 'View less'.

For some reason my code is not working and I can't understand why.

I tried changing the JS a bit and different workarounds but I can't figure it out.

I want to make it on click show more / show less

Link to codepen:

https://codepen.io/vasilkrumov/pen/YzzKzoj

```js
$('body').on('click', '.js-toggle-handle', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this)
    .find('.js-toggle-handle')
    .toggleClass('hidden')
})
```

```css
.js-toggle-handle.notification-preferences-toggle-button.desktop.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="js-toggle-handle notification-preferences-toggle-button desktop" <i class="icon-angle-up js-toggle-indicator" data-icon="arrow-up"></i>Show More</a>

<a href="#" class="js-toggle-handle notification-preferences-toggle-button desktop hidden" <i class="icon-angle-up js-toggle-indicator" data-icon="arrow-up"></i>Show Less</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` in your delegated click refers to `.js-toggle-handle` and not to `body`.

You just want this

```js
$('body').on('click', '.js-toggle-handle', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.js-toggle-handle').toggleClass('hidden')
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="js-toggle-handle notification-preferences-toggle-button desktop" <i class="icon-angle-up js-toggle-indicator" data-icon="arrow-up"></i>Show More</a>

<a href="#" class="js-toggle-handle notification-preferences-toggle-button desktop hidden" <i class="icon-angle-up js-toggle-indicator" data-icon="arrow-up"></i>Show Less</a>
```

Comment: That totally worked, however there is one small issue. I actually have those on 5-6 places on the page, so when I click one they all toggle. How can I make them to only toggle the one that is clicked?

Comment: Are each set in a separate container? Like a div, then we can use `$(this).closest(“div”).find("js-toggle-handle”).toggleClass...`